# Create a quiz with polymer or angular?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, angular-dart

I would like to create a quiz with dart. Checkboxes, radiobuttons, dropdownmenu, inputfields, ...

Furthermore I would like to load the quiz from a database, display it on a website and store also the results of a specific user to a database. Redis or mysql.

The big question for me: Should I use polymer.dart or angular.dart? Both are capeable of doing it but what would be the obvious choice?

Answer (score 6):

Polymer and Angular might look very similar because they both have templating and data-binding, but they're actually quite different.

Polymer isn't really a full application framework so much as it is a framework for creating W3C Custom Elements[1](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/web-ui/2tMZ6Hp4J1o). It relies on new, upcoming, and hopeful standards like Shadow DOM, Object.observe, Mutation Observers, Scoped CSS, the  element, Template Binding, Node.bind(), Custom Elements and HTML Imports and basically makes it easier to use them together to create custom elements. You actually don't need to use Polymer at all to create custom elements, it would just be more tedious. The Polymer *project* has also built polyfills for those standards, so it's sometimes confusing to tell which parts are the actual "polymer" part. In Dart-land it's only things in the polymer package, mostly the Polymer class, everything else is in packages like observe, template_binding, or already integrated into dart:html, like Shadow DOM.

Once you implement a custom element in Polymer, users of the element don't need to be aware of Polymer at all, it's an implementation detail. They might need to know about custom element upgrading or Node.bind(), but not Polymer. In fact, Polymer is so focused on elements, that there isn't really such a thing as a "Polymer app", there's just an app built out of custom elements, which happen to be implemented with Polymer, but they could just as easily be implemented with Mozilla's X-Tags library[2]

Angular is definitely more full featured and what I would call an "application framework", rather than a custom element framework. It provides directives (mixin behaviors for nodes), dependency injection, all kinds of services like http and routing, and has this whole mutable inherited scope idea that permeates the app, and has global state, among other things I'm probably missing. Angular currently won't help you build custom elements, instead you create Angular components that work in Angular apps.

An Angular app can use Polymer elements, since Polymer elements are just elements. One way data-binding should[3] just work, while two-way data binding will require either a custom directive (to use Object.observe or Node.bind to listen to property changes), or for Angular to add support for Node.bind(), which would allow Angular to generically two-way-bind to any element, from s to Polymer elements, to X-Tag elements.

In the end, I don't think there is a fair apples-to-apple comparison between the two, and the overlap is smaller that it might appear on the surface, because people seem to either over-estimate how big Polymer is or how under-estimate how big Angular is, or maybe they aren't aware of the differences in philosophy. I fully expect more Angular-like frameworks to appear in the future that build on top of custom elements that will be more comparable to Angular than Polymer is, and Polymer will still be a nice way, among other options, to implement the elements.

[SOURCE](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/web-ui/2tMZ6Hp4J1o)

Answer (score 2):

I worked a lot with Polymer (https://github.com/ErikGrimes/polymer_elements, https://github.com/ErikGrimes/polymer_ui_elements) and worked on a webapp based on Polymer.
I like building apps out of components a lot.

Recently I immersed into AngularDart.
Angular allows to create components too.

At the current state I would say that I find Angular more lightweight.
Not everything has to be a component, there are more lightweight constructs (direcitve, controller)
The hierarchical scope easily allows to connect everything.

I have yet to do more advanced things (like I already did with Polymer) to learn the limitations of Angular and be able to do a fair comparsion.

Both have still some glitches and limitations and are still pre 1.0
but both already allow building advanced applications
and as @Nidzaaa 's noted, they can be used in combination.